# How to show a cv::cuda::GpuMat directly with cv::imshow?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, imshow

I have meet some problems when I try to show a cv::cuda::GpuMat object with OpenCV function cv::imshow.Below are my environment

- OpenCV Version:4.5.5 build with CUDA and opengl support
- System:Windows 10 1909
- Computer Configuration:i7 9750h+16G RAM+GTX 1660ti 6G

After searching for a while,I know there are three ways to show a cv::cuda::GpuMat object with cv::imshow:

1. use the download method to transfer GpuMat to Mat,and then show the Mat object with imshow directly
2. create a window with flag cv::WINDOW_OPENGL,and then show the GpuMat object with imshow in the window created with opengl
3. create a window with flag cv::WINDOW_OPENGL,using the GpuMat to create a cv::ogl::Texture2D object and set the drawing call back function

My problem appeared in method 2.When I try to show a GpuMat directly with imshow,it give me the error msg:
OpenCV(4.5.5) F:\OpenCVWithCUDA\opencv-4.5.5\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp:111: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) You should explicitly call download method for cuda::GpuMat object in function 'cv::debug_build_guard::*InputArray::getMat*'

Here are the simple problem code:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat d_dst;//Assume that the object already has content
cv::namedWindow("highgui(OpenGL)", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);
cv::imshow("highgui(OpenGL)", d_dst);
```

matrix_wrap.cpp which define the Input/Output Array.In function:

```
Mat _InputArray::getMat_(int i) const
{
...
    if( k == CUDA_GPU_MAT )
    {
        CV_Assert( i < 0 );
        CV_Error(cv::Error::StsNotImplemented, "You should explicitly call download method for cuda::GpuMat object");
    }
}
```

But the method 3 work well:

```
cv::namedWindow("highgui(Texture2D)", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);
cv::ogl::Texture2D texture(d_dst);
cv::resizeWindow("highgui(Texture2D)", d_dst.cols, d_dst.rows);
cv::setOpenGlContext("highgui(Texture2D)");
cv::setOpenGlDrawCallback("highgui(Texture2D)", drawTexture_cb, &texture);
cv::updateWindow("highgui(Texture2D)");

void drawTexture_cb(void* userdata)
    {
        cv::ogl::Texture2D* texture = static_cast<cv::ogl::Texture2D*>(userdata);
        cv::ogl::render(*texture);
    }
```

According to my search,method 3 seems to be the internal implement of method 2,but why it doesn't work?Is there anything wrong with my own building opencv(The error msg above show The function/feature is not implemented)?

Comment: Because you posted yourself that expression k == CUDA_GPU_MAT is true.

Comment: Sorry,but I don't know what you mean.When I debug,it threw error when code ran to that expression k == CUDA_GPU_MAT.Do you have any idea to show a GpuMat object directlty with imshow?Thank you.